# He/She/It on Imaginary/Fantasy figures

Tags: american-english

Consider that you have a fantasy figure, when writing a comic/book. Could you refer to this figure as he/she without being grammatically incorrect?

*Example:* Daffy Duck likes **his** new boat. Because now **he** can sing "I'm on a boat".

Comment: Are you asking whether or not it is correct to write `he/she` or whether one pronoun is correct?

Comment: Definitely he respectively she ;)

Comment: You might want to ask this on writers.se and/or research anthropomorphism and gender systems further on scifi.se.

Comment: General Reference. Presumably anyone writing a comic/book with "fantasy" characters will have read other such books, and noticed that Donald Duck, for example, is never referred to as "it".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks! Not writing a fantasy/comic book but a techical book. There's a "character" that shows up here and there with tips&tricks, so I wanted to know if I should say he/she/it. :)

Comment: oic - you mean like the Microsoft Microsoft Office Assistant *(Clippy)*. All I can say is I think most people call it an "it", and it [has been deprecated in the 2007 release of Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa433261(v=office.12).aspx). People in general don't like distractions like that on screen -they're probably less bothered by static images in books, but I doubt many readers would be so taken with such "doodles" as to anthropomorphise them into "he/she".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm *Not* adding something like Clippy in the book!  I don't think many readers would care either, I'm just curious what is correct/most common.

Comment: Yeah - I got that from your last comment. There's no concept of "correct" usage if you're just referring to a "character" in the artwork of, say, one of those *"XXX for Dummies"* books. But as I said, I expect most readers would call it "it", but the author, publisher, and illustrator would probably like us to "warm to it", and call it "he/she".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suspension of one's normal firm grasp on reality needed to 'enter into' a work of fiction, where human attributes / emotions are ascribed to inanimate objects or animals, is known as engaging with 'pathetic fallacy'. The more fanciful the fiction, the greater the leap of imagination required. (The attributing of human characteristics to sub- (or super-human) persons / creatures / objects is also known as 'anthropomorphism'.)
Consistency is usually needed to avoid total confusion (I don't know how Walt Disney got away with a non-speaking Pluto and a speaking Goofy).
If Daffy Duck can sing "I'm on a boat", he's a he (assuming Daffy is male).

Comment: Pluto is a "he" because he's a male dog, even though not anthropomorphized like Goofy. Consider also Lightning McQueen (a personified racecar) and _his_ "girlfriend", a light blue Porshe. _her_ name is Sally.